# Suddenly no POST with 2 or more RAM sticks

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I been running a systems with all 4 RAM slots used, all the ram is HyperX Fury Black DDR4 2666Mhz, and it had all been working fine (after tuning the DRAM voltage to 1.3v) for a couple of month.
I recently bought a NVME ssd, and started reinstall windows amd Manjaro dual boot on that, and transferred files and setting.
I have several harddisk that I disconnect while doing this. After a day everything was ready to be installed back it. I plugged all my SATA hard drives back in and booted, worked fine, but noticed one of my SATA hard drives was not showing up. Turn off the computer and disconnect 1 after 1 to try to find which one it was (they were not labelled).
While doing this suddenly my mobo (ROG B450-F) lit a yellow light and refused to POST.
I looked up the what the yellow light meant in the manual: DRAM issues. This confused me has during this whole process, I had neither touched the RAM sticks, nor changed any setting in the Bios, except boot order

### What I tried:

Unplug all the SATA drives was my first reaction, still no luck.
Reluctanty I disconnect all except 1 Sticks (the one under my CPU fan remained) Then it booted.
Added a stick in the dual lane (a1+b1), no luck.
Moved it to the a2 slot, it booted (a1+a2) .
Moved it to the b2 slot, no luck (a1+b2).
Changed bios setting to default:
I.E voltage back to 1.2v and disable XMP, and some CPU OC removed. Same behaviour as described above.
**update**
Had stick in a1 a2 b2, that POSTed
**update2**
With exact same stick and position, it no longer POST in a1 a2 b2. Can't seem to re-create the 3 sticks in situation.

### Things I haven't tried

Plugging in 1 and 1 ram, due to the fact that I would rather not unscrew my CPU fan, as I have no more thermo past, and it's a pain. Also because I ran memtest86 (note the earlier issue where I tuned the voltage up to 1.3v) and all my sticks ran fine when the voltage got increased. I also have tested the a1 a2 slot combination on the remaning RAM, and that does work.
Reseating the CPU, again similar to above, but I am going todo it, unless someone has a potential solution that doesn't require me removing my CPU fan

### specs

CPU: Ryzen 5 3600
RAM: HyperX Fury Black DDR4 2666Mhz  (x4)
Motherboard: Asus ROG B450-F
Graphics Card: Zotac GeForce RTX 2070 Super
NVME SSD: WD Black SN750 1TB

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem with my computer, just an Intel 4th gen and DDR3, just as stomped as you.